# Visual Studio Unable to read memory for certain members of struct.

Tags: c, visual-studio, struct, header

I'm having a difficult time due to a weird error which I can't figure out.
I have a header file(myheader.h) which defines a struct with bunch of unsigned int variable members(~4500 variables) as below.

```
myheader.h

typedef struct MYPARAM MYPARAM;

struct MYPARAM
{ 
 unsigned int param1 :1;
 unsigned int param2 :1;
 unsigned int param3 :1;
 ...
 unsigned int param4500 :1;
 };
```

And in my .c code I include the header and initialize the MYPARAM struct pointer as below.

```
mycode.c

#incldue "myheader.h"
int main()
{
 MYPARAM *pmyparam;
 MYPARAM my_param;
 pmyparam=&my_param;
 printf("print anything");   <-- break point here.
}
```

Now my problem is that... for no reason, when I watch pmyparam at the break point, I get "unable to read memory" for the last two members. 
I've tried deleting members until I don't see the message, at the 2446th member, one of the "unable to read memory" goes away and at the 469th the other message disappear. In other word, no matter what variable I declare if the number of members exceed 469, I get "unable to read memory" for the last member and when exceed 2446, I get last two members "unable to read memory" message.
Fyi, this code was totally fine on linux machine with gcc compiler.
Any idea will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "when I watch `pmyparam`" --> The code that implements the "watch" has a limitation - perhaps due to a local object limit. Does the program itself fail?

Comment: hm...my real problem is actually when I pass pmyparam into a dll function that updates members of MYPARAM. It updates properly if I print "pmyparam->param#" inside dll function but after the function call ends, if I print "pmyparam->param#" from the main function, it doesn't have updated value. I thought it might be due to memory corruption as "unable to read memory" message indicated. :(

Comment: I suspect that the large local object `my_param` is the issue - not its large number of members. Suggest `MYPARAM my_param;
 pmyparam=&my_param;` --> `pmyparam = malloc(sizeof *pmyparam);` and see if the problem remains.

Comment: I've tried it but it's the same... :( And for your information, I also cannot access or assign any values to the last two members.  If I try  `pmyparam->lastmember=1;` this fails.

Comment: Suggest posting the true code that demonstrates the dll function call and troubles.

Comment: Wish I can post all, but the entire code is huge...and also confidential.. Sorry that I can't post all.... but the problem above retains when evan with small example..

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can recreate the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: @chux It seems "watch" function itself indeed has a limitation. I could access the "unable to read" member value and assign different value. I did not know ":1;" means defining a bit field which makes the variable to have only 1 or 0. I was confused that I could not assign any value for those members after trying assigning a number higher than 1. Now I at least know that my real problem is not due to this issue. Thanks!